# Should I store AWS S3 style object storage key in a database?

Tags: database, object, amazon-s3, storage, aws-sdk

As described above, should I store object storage keys in database for the purpose of searching, aggregating etc.? What best practice you have?

Appreciated for any suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known practice to use AWS DynamoDB as a metadata store for S3 objects for searching and listing objects based on objects metadata.

However if you need full text search on objects (e.g Text files in S3) you might need to consider using an indexing service such as AWS Elastic Search. You can also use AWS Athena if the query time is not that significant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ashan! So I guess if I need to search files specifying some conditions, it should be great to store the metadata in DynamoDB (or other databases)